# introduction to setup test server

Tags: php, testing, dreamweaver

I uses Dreamweaver, and I have a domain hosted on a public hosting company.

Currently, as I am editing my .php, I have to constantly upload to my domain to test it out.
I don't really want to setup a local server like xampp as I want to be able to access to most updated of my site across multiple companies and anywhere.

My site is still in very early stage of development.

Is this the typical work flow? 'coz it's pretty annoying to me.

Thanks

Comment: "Live" data without all the prep work? if you find a way, let me know. Otherwise, make a sandbox locally and only push "stable" builds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are your options:

1. Develop locally, push your changes to a remote server
2. Develop locally, use a local lamp / wamp setup to instantly see your changes
3. Develop remotely either over ssh or remote desktop. View your changes instantly.

Comment: The 2nd option wouldn't satisfy my need to have access to my DB on other computers, would it?


Could you elaborate on the 3rd option?
Is that the same as if I switch to remote view for my files in Dreamweaver, and practically edit them on the server

Comment: No, because you're still editing files locally, which are then instantly copied to the server, which is #1. With the 3rd option, you remote in to your server, run an editor *on the server* and do your work that way. It's nice for prototyping, but you really should heed the advice given by Timo.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I am really prototyping, I will vote for your answer.

Answer (score 6):

What usually happens is that you run multiple servers. It's generally **very bad** practice to edit the actual website immediately. What if you create a bug? You must certainly will, since nobody programs flawless. There's a paradigm called DTAP

1. Development
2. Test
3. Acceptance
4. Production

You develop op your development server, there you can do anything you want. Just mess around and try around stuff until you think you've created a new version. Then upload it to the test server, where you only update a full new version of the website. You can test and see if everything work.

When you have created and tested a new version, you can upload it to the acceptance server, where the customer can see if it for fills it's needs. And when that's done you can upload it to the development server.

Obviously, I understand that in some projects this is a big overkill. So you might want to merge the testing and the development on one server. But what's most important of this is. **Make sure development and production is divided**. So changes you do, do not immediately reflect on the production server, so if you create bugs, it wont affect the website.

Also, it doesn't even have to be different physical servers, it may also be just different websites on the same server like:

- dev.example.com
- test.example.com
- acceptance.example.com
- example.com

Also make sure you work on different versions of your software. Don't publish just tiny bits. But every time make sure you work towards a new "version" of the website, containing new functionality every time you upload it. Make sure you have certain goals you want to work to like:

Add forum to website, add blog to website, add chatbox to website. And only publish it to production when it's done completely.

Also, if you work in these updates, it's very easy deploy. You just upload a complete website, instead of just ftp'ing different single php file.

---

I think in your case it would be best to create a subdomain on your host. Then duplicate the database (you could make something to automate this) and site. That way you have the most up-to-date version. When you've created something, push it to the default site.

Comment: @Timo: I completely agree with this methodology, however if it's a small enough site or there are no users, you can get away with modifying the live site -- if only for a while. In other words, for prototyping this may be overkill. I'm still giving you +1 though.

Comment: Yes Chris, I absolutly agree with you. Actually, I think I might discourage using the full DTAP methodology for very small websites. It just creates complexity that's never been used. On my personal websites, there's no use for acceptance server, since I'm the one who does the functionality checks. But I think knowing what's the best in ideal situations makes it possible to make good decisions on what to do.

Comment: Awesome answer. Awesome paradigm. Not so awesome spelling of 'devided'. :P

Comment: Thank you. I will keep this in mind, and when I have moved beyond prototyping, this will be the procedure I will follow